# Fortigate, convertir interfaz en Software Switch, debug de fichero de comando

Tags: script, router, cli, routing

**Contexto/situación:**

Dispongo de un Fortigate 600E trabajando estupéndamente.
Maneja mas de 200 VLANS, varias WANs con SD-WAN, múltiples politicas... Todo funcionando bien.

Un nuevo requerimiento es el transportar una VLAN que lleva una ip publica hacia una localización remota a través de un puerto SFP.

Esta VLAN está dentro de un SD-WAN, tiene varios IP-Pool, varios VIPs...

Para transportarla hemos pensado en convertir el interfaz a Software Switch.

Me he descargado el Backup del Router, y editando el fichero de configuración a mano he creado el correspondiente Software Switch, incluido las interfaces físicas, cambiadas todas las referencias...

**Nota:**
Mi preocupación es que el nuevo fichero de configuración tenga algún error tipográfico (sintaxis) y la carga del mismo resulte en un desastre.

**Consulta**
He buscado sin éxito herramientas para hacer debug/resaltado a los comandos del fichero tal cual lo hacen los editores como notepad++ al programar comandos en otros lenguajes de configuración/programación, quiero hacer esto antes de cargarlo en real.

¿Existe alguna configuración a los editores oficial o no oficial (Herramientas de programación) para que me ayude en esta tarea?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo leer [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En este caso,diría que tu pregunta no encaja en el sitio dado que no parece tener nada que ver con programación, sino con administración de sistemas

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque es un probema de configuracion de hardware

Comment: En la red hay sitios especificos para lo que es administracion y configuracion de hardware.

Comment: @Pikoh ya le realice una actualización a la pregunta del OP esta pedniente que la aprueben ... basado en este comentario: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56811281#56811281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**La solución es simple Manualmente:**

1. crear dos fichero, un backup y crear una copia del backup (backup1 y backup2).
2. Verificar que el backup1 (sin tocar, modificar) sea funciona y puedas restablecer el equipo sin ningún inconveniente, de paso si vez que en la restauración hay cosas que no se cargaron correctamente; crear una mini guía o procedimiento para arreglar (hacer fix) de cualquier anomalía.
3. teniendo el punto 1 y 2 finalizados, en backup2 es donde harás los cambios, si hay algún error de sintaxis el backup2 no te funcionara.

De esta manera puedes certificar la integridad del ultimo estado funcional de la configuración. realmente no existen herramientas que yo sepa para verificar el código de los archivos de Backup o hacerles debug a la sintaxis a menos que sea un lenguaje ya conocido de programación, estos archivos no esta destinado a ser programados manualmente, están destinados solo a ser backup de extensas configuraciones del dispositivo y hacer la portabilidad fácil.

**La solución usando Herramientas de Programación:**

es muy probable que sea necesario un plugin de highlight para algún editor.

**Update: encontre eso dentro de las Herramientas que comunmente usamos para programar:**

por ejemplo ATOM ofrece soporte para el scripting de Cisco:
https://atom.io/packages/language-cisco

y tambien para Fortigate, pero no ofrecen debug:
https://atom.io/packages/language-fortigate

---

Te puedo recomendar solicitar soporte al fabricante del dispositivo.
Si Existe la herramientas y estas certificado muy probablemente te la faciliten.

Comment: Gracias!
Los puntos 1 y 2 los ejecuté sin problema. El equipo me toma el backup sin editar, se reinicia y todo funciona normal. 
He Probado tambien haciendo cambios y luego volviendo hacia atrás con el backup, todo bien.
Ok, entonces si hay un error de sintáxis directamente la restauración falla, es bueno saberlo.
Pediré soporte tambien a Fortinet Dominicana.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: a lo mejor el te puede sugerir con quien en soporte hablar del tema.

Comment: @EnekoRojo he actualizado mi respuesta y he agregado herramientas que no he probado pero que tal vez solucionen tu problema.

Comment: Nuñez. He probado el plugin de Atom y me es de gran ayuda! Lamento haber generado polémica.

Comment: De nada amigo algunos aun tenemos Fe en la Humanidad.

Comment: @EnekoRojo en ningun caso debes disculparte, no ha sido tu pregunta la que ha generado la polémica. Como usuario nuevo, es normal que no conozcas en profundidad las normas del sitio. Eres totalmente bienvenido para cualquier pregunta relacionada con la programación, pero para sistemas hay otros sitios en la red, por ejemplo https://serverfault.com/ (lamentablemente solo en inglés)

Comment: Qué barbaridad con lo de votar por temas no relacionados con la publicación. Esta respuesta puede o no ser buena, pero no tiene ningún sentido cascarle 4 votos negativos porque el autor dijo esto o aquello en otro sitio. Flaco favor estamos haciendo a la distribución y evaluación de conocimiento.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' por ese motivo solicite bloquear la pregunta ... independientemente de lo que haya pasado no le veo sentido a los votos negativos, es mas lo veo como acoso  de parte de la misma comunidad y de los moderadores que se les indica que esto esa pasando y lo permiten ... por que no revierten los votos negativos...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez, estoy de acuerdo contigo, hay cosas con las que simplemente no concuerdo.